# a Devise model that could belong to another Devise model, but not necessarily.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

I'm building something with the `User` and `Page` model, kind of like FB. Devise has been added to both of these models. I want it so a page can be created by a user and belong to them, or a page can be created under a whole new account (no public `User` managing it). What do I need to change in my models for this?

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :likes
  has_many :users, :through => :likes
  has_many :events
end
```

doesn't seem like adding `belongs_to :user` here is correct, since it's not always true

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :likes
  has_many :pages, :through => :likes
end
```

Comment: Just add association in `Page`: `belongs_to :user` as a page can belong to single user, and in `User`: `has_many :pages` as a user can create multiple pages. The `Page` model should have a `user_id` column.

Comment: @Deep Will it still be possible to create user-independent Pages? Meaning, since Devise has been added to the Page model as well, a Page will have its own email/password login.

Comment: Yes it would be possible unless you have a validation that checks the presence of user_id and says it should be there always. In the user independent pages the user_id would be nil